# How can I use external files as resources for MessageSource?

Tags: spring-boot

I created validation annotation classes such as `@IpV4`, `@IpV4List` in library packages. These annotations return the key (code) that can be used in the `MessageSource` when the validation is violated.

`message.properties` files are in the common resource folder, and each module that uses annotations in library package will attempt to specify the path when registering `MessageSource` bean.

However, when an annotation raises an exception such as `MethodArgumentNotValidException`, `MessageSource`  does not find any messages with message template (code defined in the annotation).

I have tried most of the methods posted on StackOverFlow related to this issue.

1. basename in application.properties (without static-location)

```
spring.messages.basename=messages/messages, file:/path/to/file
```

2. basename in `@Configuration` class (without static-location)

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource(){
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("messages/messages", "file:/path/to/file");
    // some other settings...
    return messageSource;
}
```

3. static resource location in application.properties

```
spring.messages.basename=messages/messages, messages/vailidation_messages
spring.resources.static-locations=file:/path/to/parent_of_messages
```

4. static resource location in ```@Configuration` class

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("file:/path/to/parent_of_messages")
    // some other settings
    ;
}
```

I tried many other approaches, but I could not get a message from calling `MessageSource.getMessage()`, and `ConstraintViolationException` occurred.

The structure of my projects is as follows.

```
foo-cloud
│
├─ foo-config
│  ├─ resources
│  │  ├─ messages << message properties here
│  │  │  ├─ validation_messages.properties
│  │  │  ├─ validation_messages_en.properties
│  │  │  ├─ validation_messages_ja.properties
│  │  │  └─ validation_messages_ko.properties
│  │  └─ ...
│  └─ ...
├─ foo-auth
├─ ...
├─ foo-gateway
│
├─ foo-resource
│  ├─ ...
│  ├─ foo-application << module to register Bean for MessageSource here
│  └─ ...
│
├─ foo-library
│  ├─ ...
│  └─ util-lib << annotation for validation here
│ 
└─ foo-web
   └─ ...
```

- application-dev.properties (current, `edited`)

```
spring.messages.basename=messages/messages, messages/validation_messages # <- how to fix?
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
# spring.resources.static-locations=file:../../foo-config/resources #not used anymore
```

- IpV4 class in library package

```
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE_USE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Target({ FIELD, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Pattern(regexp = IpV4.PATTERN, message = IpV4.NOT_MATCH)
@NotEmpty(message = IpV4.NOT_EMPTY)
public @interface IpV4 {

    String  PATTERN     = "^(([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";
    String  NOT_EMPTY   = "validation.ip-v4.not_empty";
    String  NOT_MATCH   = "validation.ip-v4.not_match";

    String message() default "invalid ip format";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

- ExceptionHandler class

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public Map<String, String> validationExceptionCaught(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
    return Collections.singletonMap("message", messageSource.getMessage(
            e.getBindingResult().getFieldError().getDefaultMessage()));
}

/**
 * for debugging
 */
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public Map<String, String> validationExceptionCaught(
        MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException e) {
    return Collections.singletonMap("message", e.getMessage());
}

@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public Map<String, String> validationExceptionCaught(
        ConstraintViolationException e) {
    return Collections.singletonMap("message",
            messageSource.getMessage(
                    e.getConstraintViolations().stream().findFirst()
                            .map(ConstraintViolation::getMessageTemplate)
                            .orElse(e.getMessage())));
}
```

- DTO class uses @IpV4 annotation

```
import foo.bar.lib.common.validator.IpV4;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class BarRequest {
    @IpV4
    private String startIp;
    @IpV4
    private String endIp;
    private String description;
}
```

How can I use external files as resources for MessageSource To share verification messages?

I am afraid that my English skill is not good enough to communicate.

Comment: It isn't an external file it is a class path resource. Prefix your locations with `classpath:`. Also trying to specify the resource location will do exactly nothing for the `MessageSource` as that is about resource resolving not messages.

Comment: @M.Deinum It seems that source file is contaminated by various combination of search results. When I set `static-location`, I set `basename` to `messages/validation_message` without `file:`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I fixed the misleading part of the post.

Comment: `static-location` has nothing to do with messages but resolving static content and views.

Comment: @M.Deinum Understood. So is there any way to use an external file as a resource for `MessageSource`?

Comment: By properly configuring the right property. However these aren't external files they are just part of the classpath.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have already removed `static-location` from the `application-dev.properties` file. Then, how could I use foo-config/resources/messages files for `MessageSource` in `foo-application`?

Comment: I assume that `foo-config` is also being packaged as a jar and is a dependency of your project?

Comment: @M.Deinum `foo-config` is a project, but resources is not in classpath. It's just folder in local environment, and resources folder is a repository deployed to specific location in stage environment.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I solved this problem.

The problem was that the configuration file was twisted or there was a typo in the file path while trying various methods.

I removed all properties related to `MessageSource` from the `application.properties` file and registered `MessageSource` bean in `@Configuration` class as the following source.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages/messages",
            "file:D:/foo-cloud/foo-config/resources/messages_validation");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(600);
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    return messageSource;
}
```

Thanks to `M.Deinum` for helping me.

Comment: I was supposed to read the properties from the multiple locations, first from external and if not present then from the classpath. This worked for me. Thanks a lot!